# TX 1000 Nvidia driver problem

Tags: nvidia, compiz

Hello

I installed the new ubuntu the other day and installed all the drivers and then restart the laptop. then i get the login screen with no problem then when i login the black screen in about 10 mins a window popup saying that the application compiz has closed unexpectedly i relaunch the app. and then it happens again.

I have uninstalled nvidia driver then restarted and the OS works fine.. tryed older driver and still the same problem. anyone out there can help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, fixed by installing the [latest Nvidia driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-302.07-driver.html).

Comment: @EliahKagan Correct! Being a jackass is never fun :/ If downloading a new driver from their site is what is enough to fix this then the post should be considered a answer. I have deleted both comments, feel free to flag these 2 when you see them.